# remove bootstrap 3 tabs href hash name from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with this [plugin](https://github.com/thecodeassassin/bootstrap-remote-data) for bootstrap tabs load remote data using json.

this worked for me but in action, show tabs `href="#callback"` in my url.

`http://mydomain/#callback` or `http://mydomain/#jsondata` this is bad idea. I need to remove this `hash href` from my url.

I remove `href` and replace with `#` Or `javascript:void(0)` and plugin not work.

how do fix this problem?

DEMO [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/88qgo4om/)

Comment: Having difficulty seeing the issue. jsfiddles don't show urls. can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @CHoltzman: `http://mydomain/#callback`

Answer (score 0):

The url is dead, but from what I see in your code, the href says: 
     
whatever text is between the ""of the href in the link tag, is the text that will show in the url because that is the div or page or section its linked to. Therefore if you want it changed, then you have to rename the corresponding div and any code related to it. If you are using a id to link the div then the hash sign is unavoidable.